# Why can't one reheat wok noodles?

Tags: food-safety, reheating, noodles

Most packages of ready noodles contain the information not to reheat them, for example: https://groceries.asda.com/product/noodles/asda-straight-to-wok-noodles/910002208900. It's safe to reheat rice, pasta etc., so I'm confused why reheating wok noodles would be different.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, just an opinion, based on my most-frequented supermarket being Asda ;) - their fresh ones, top of the veg aisle near the boxes of fresh stir-fry veg are much better than those - they just have a shorter use-by date. [& you can't re-cook those either, though they'll stand keeping the leftovers in the fridge overnight & microwaving for a quick lunch] Also cheaper, but more fat content - https://groceries.asda.com/product/view-all-stir-fry/asda-egg-noodles/1000009333665

Answer (score 7):

The "do not reheat" is standard text on food that's already cooked (like these noodles) with the expectation you'll cook it again. So they expect you to reheat once by stir-frying, then not again. You don't need to heat them before adding to a wok, but that's not what they're referring to.

The reasoning is usually about total time at  temperatures ideal for bacteria to grow - if food is cooked, cooled, heated, cooled and heated again the total can get close to the limits. I routinely ignore that text on the basis that I cool my leftovers quickly (and reheat them quickly from chilled), but I can't really recommend you do the same. It's not just that they're covering themselves against other people's behaviour, but there is an element of that.